# "Not that I heard of". Is this a somewhat shortened form of a full sentence?

Tags: phrases, american-english, phrase-usage

"Not that I heard of."

I understand its meaning, but It sounds like a somewhat shortened form of a full sentence. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is shortened from "**It's not that I heard of.**", but it can be used (and is normally used) without first part.

Comment: It's short for "It's not something that I've heard of"

Comment: A minimal change to make it a full sentence, with the same meaning, is to replace “Not” with “There is no such thing” or “It never happened”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common  idiomatic turn; there is a similar one, "not that I know of" that is used in a similar  context but much more frequently ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+that+I%27ve+heard+of%2Cnot+that+I+heard+of%2Cnot+that+I+know+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20that%20I%20heard%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20that%20I%20know%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnot%20that%20I%20heard%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20that%20I%20know%20of%3B%2Cc0)). Apparently, "**not that I've heard of**" is not used ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+that+I%27ve+heard+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)).

This turn is used in answer to a question. You can consider it to be the shortening of anything that makes sense. For instance, in the dialogue below there are at least four options you can use instead.

- *Att.Gen.* Was there any discourse at that time Mr Coote?
  *Pomfret* Not that I heard of, one word.
- Not *any discourse* that I heard of, one word.
  Not *any* that I heard of, one word.
  *There was* not *any discourse* that I heard of, one word.
  *There was* not *any* that I heard of, one word.

Most often, when you can use "not that I heard of", "not that I know of" can be used in its place.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fragment suggesting a response to an interrogative. The right forms are "not that **I've heard** of" or "not that **I know** of".

Comment: You do say also "Not that I heard of.". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Not+that+I+heard+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNot%20that%20I%20heard%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CNot%20that%20I%20heard%20of%3B%2Cc0